# Target Div state in show/hide js

Tags: javascript, html, css, show-hide

Ok So I'm using this bit of coding here to show and hide a div in a tab switch style basis: http://jsfiddle.net/AXj53/4/

```
    jQuery('a[id^="link"]').click(function(){
    var vid_id = jQuery(this).attr("id").replace("link", "#testVid");
    jQuery('div[id^="testVid"]').hide();
    jQuery(vid_id).show();
```

I want to make the state of a hover and the state of a selected div but I cant seem to get it working, is there anything I can do with the JS to give the hover and selected links a kind of inset shadow?

All help much appreciated.

Comment: Include relevant code into the question.

Comment: I've put it all in jsFiddle but the bit I want to change state on select is the css

`.left{font-family:'helvetica_bqregular'; color:#666; display:inline-block; width:145px; border:thin solid #CCC; text-align:center; background-color:#eee; border-radius:4px; border-top-right-radius:0px; border-bottom-right-radius:0px; margin-left:13px; margin-top:9px; margin-bottom:10px;padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px;}`

Comment: Please edit the question and put relevant code there, not in the comments.

Comment: if i understood correctly, you would like to know which tab is active and style the button. this code should be the solution. http://jsfiddle.net/AXj53/8/

It adds an "active" css class on the currently selected tab so that you can style it with css

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in JS, but its easier to leverage the CSS selectors :active and :hover which don't require JS event binding.  You can also add a CSS style for the selected item and then toggle which element gets the .selected class inside the click event's callback.

Updated your jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/AXj53/16/ adding the CSS selectors for :hover, :active, and .selected and the element class toggling in JS:

```
$(this).addClass('selected');
$(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
```